# After login Home page loads and then gets refreshed not able to identify the locators due to refresh

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating the salesforce web application. After logging into the application the home page loads and then gets refreshed not able to identify the locators due to the refresh happens after 2 to 3 sec. Refresh is happing to load the dashboards.

`Getting an Exception:org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element`

I had tried with **webdriverwait**, **Thread.sleep** and **Implicitwait** and none of these options worked out for me.

```
public void validatedashboard() throws InterruptedException{
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Open')]")));
        String actualdashboard = dashboard.getText();
        BasePage.Log.info(actualdashboard);
        String ExpectedText0= "Territory Overview";

        if(actualdashboard.contentEquals(ExpectedText0))
        {
            BasePage.Log.info("Territory Overview dashboard is present");                           
        }
        else
        {
            BasePage.Log.info("Territory Overview dashboard is not present");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting for visible, then waiting for stale (page refresh), and then waiting for visible again?

Comment: @JeffC I think the problem is somewhere else. OP gets `NoSuchElementException` but `WebDriverWait` would throw `TimeoutException` instead

Comment: You will need to add some more information, the locator used to find `dashboard` would be a useful start.  Maybe a link to the site under test?

Comment: @Fenio Agreed... I was just addressing the overall approach to finding the element after the page refreshes. But your point on the type of exception is correct... that exception is not going to be thrown by the code that is currently posted.

Comment: I suspect the dashboard might be in iframe. Have you checked if there are any iframes on the page after refresh

Comment: I had checked the dashboard and its not in an iframe.

Comment: Please find the locator used to find the dashboard,                                               @FindBy(xpath= "//*[contains(text(),'Territory Over')]")   
private WebElement dashboard;